# On reset with submit in react-use-form, its not getting reset to default value ,derived from the react state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

On reset with submit in react-use-form, its not getting reset to default value ,derived from the react state?

please find the codesandbox link attached.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-hook-form-reset-usefieldarray-forked-h8jb43?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Steps to reproduce :

1. Click on append and select any one of the option. Enter corresponding lastName value.
2. Repeat step one with different option.
3. Submit it. it will console out and the state (submittedData) must be updated.
4. Now append one more field , select option and fill lastName value, but don't click on submit.
5. Click on reset.

Expected to happen:

1. When clicked on reset (step 5) , it would have set the default values derived from the (submittedData) state, i.e. only two options should be there with the last submitted values.

Also one of the requirement after submit if the old registered field firstName option is changed the corresponding lastName field should get reset to blank value. I tried using onChange event and resetField function, but its not working.

I am new to both react and react-use-form, therefore apart from code mistakes any suggestions to make it better are welcomed...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`useForm` `defaultValues` should be an object, but in your code it is a function. You have to call the `defaultValue` function and then use object spread as below.

```
const { control, handleSubmit, reset, formState, resetField } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { ...defaultValue() }
  });
```

Comment: thanks @Sreekar for the answer... I realized my mistake just after posting the question.. but for the second part of the question I did it the help of _update_  function , resetField function was not working as expected...